# Speedup ListCorrelation when using generalized correlation function

Tags: performance-tuning, convolution

ImageCorrelation provides several general function that can be used to replace the default `Dot` function. For example, in the documentation of ImageCorrelation, there is an example using `CosineDistance` as a general function:

[image]

```
ImageCorrelate[p, kr, CosineDistance ]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.006005, Null} *)
```

We can see that the example runs very fast, and it's almost as fast as the default `Dot` version

```
ImageCorrelate[p, kr ]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.004939, Null} *)
```

`ImageCorrelate` supports several general correlation functions such as `SquaredEuclideanDistance`, `ManhattanDistance` etc, and all of them have the about the same performance as the default one.

So I'm trying to do the similar thing to my data using ListCorrelation.

```
pData = ImageData[p];
krData = ImageData[kr];

Dimensions[pData]
Dimensions[krData]
(* {200, 150} *)
(* {50, 30} *)

ListCorrelate[krData, pData, {1, -1}, {}, (#1 - #2)^2 &, Plus]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {38.7298, Null} *)
```

We can see that `ListCorrelate` is much slower, and it is orders of magnitudes slower than the default `Dot` function

```
ListCorrelate[krData, pData]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.001633, Null} *)
```

So is there a way to speedup `ListCorrelate` to the same level of `ImageCorrelate`, for commonly used general functions in ImageCorrelate such as `SquaredEuclideanDistance`, `CosineDistance` etc?

Comment: The generalised version of `ListCorrelate` was always a real lot slower than the default (which is a shame because it opens up some nice usage possibilities). So unless some rewriting of the function too place recently you are not likely to match or get close the speed of the other function.

Comment: Might get modest improvement by using Compile on theoptional function.

Answer (score 5):

... 3 years later at least for 2D  problems:

```
ImageCorrelate[pData//Image, krData, CosineDistance]//ImageData
```